# Having problems with sessions not allowing flow from isset to isset in same page

Tags: php, session

I have a page titled "test.php"

When I remove all session statements it works fine.  However I wish to create session for security purposes (cannot get in without verification).

After the user enters username and password they are taken to the verify section where they click on "Continue".  This then goes to a list of tests that they can select to take.  But when they click on the test, only the template is displayed and no data.  If I remove session info, everything works well.

Would appreciate assistance
Phil

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

some basic html here (title metadate etc.  nothing pertinent to the workings of this page)

<?php

// =========================================   session 
if(isset($_SESSION['stud_id'])) {

     $student=$_SESSION["student"] ;
     $stud_id=$_SESSION["stud_id"] ;

// =========================================  login screen
if(!isset($_POST['logged']) )  { 

$page_content ="log in screen
";
} // close isset login screen

// =========================================  verify password and username
if(isset($_POST['verify']) )  { 

$page_content ="Welcome and continue screen  ==> goes to test list  
     ";

} // close isset verify username and psw


// ========================================= test list
if(isset($_POST['list']) )  { 


$page_content =" Presents test areas  ==> on selection goes to test questions
     ";

} // close isset list   questions


=========================================    take test
if(isset($_POST['questions']) )  { 


$page_content  =" answer questions and ==> goes to score
";

}  // close isset questions

// ========================================= scoring
if(isset($_POST['score']) )  { 

$page_content =" scores test, updates student record  === this is the end of the test === process
 "; 

  } // close isset score


// ========================================= clsose session

} // close if session

// remove all session variables
session_unset();

// destroy the session
session_destroy(); 

?>

</head>

<body>
<?php  
 $content = $page_content;

include('template.php');      =======  template for standard look page =========

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have all the $_POST and $_SESSION data when you enter this page from another page ?

Comment: I am thinking that the if(isset($_SESSION['stud_id'])) statement needs to go or placed elsewhere.   Destroying the session when the test is completed is also important as is the inability of the student to go back and "correct" incorrect answers for a higher score.

Comment: There is no $_POST or $_SESSION info that is supposed to be passed to this page.  All info is internal from the login to test scoring and mysql updating of student record

Answer (score 0):

What I was attempting to do was to have a login along with an online test.  In retrospect, I created a separate login page that created
$_SESSION["stud_id"] = $student_id;
$_SESSION["student"] = "$student";

On the test page "if(isset($_SESSION['stud_id'])) {" and its corresponding closing bracket were removed and an if exist id and name code inserted as a form of verifying the student login.